# where can I find the main sidebar file location?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, account-dashboard

[image]

I am trying to get the location of this sidebar list I have shared with the image. where can I get that??

Comment: is it the custome account section ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look into this file..

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/collapsible.phtml

This sidebar section coming from here in My Account page.

You can override this file in your custom theme.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

Content for this file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main.account_nav">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Customer::html/collapsible.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you need to create one template file here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/html/collapsible.phtml

You can copy below file's content there and you can make any modifications there..

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/collapsible.phtml

Hope this will help you!

Comment: did you tried this then ?

Comment: thank you, sir. but after applying the method you write above, I lost the sidebar. If you tell me what to do now it would be very helpful.

Comment: Okay give me few mins..

Comment: sure, Sir. I am here.

Comment: I've corrected my answer. template file path was wrong there. Please add your new template file here.. **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/html/collapsible.phtml**

Comment: Approve my answer and give me an upvote if this solution will helps you! Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks Buddy. :) Happy to help you. :)

Comment: Sir, I need major help, if you can help me. have you seen my other ask?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. You want to add toggle there I think. Am I Right ?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me so I didn't reply there.

Comment: yes, Sir. I want to toggle there. but right now it is taking me to another page. I am really new to Magento.

Comment: Yes, You are right. But I didn't make any changes related to that, and also not sure if that is possible or not.

Comment: I need that one very badly but do not know the way. If it is not Magento then I can do that but in Magento, I can not do that.

Comment: Because for all sidebar links there are different Blocks, Layouts and Actions. SO there may be not possible to add toggle. Because for toggle we need to render all tabs data together and that is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But if you get any solution for that then please let me know.

Comment: I did not disapprove, Sir.

Comment: I made a mistake that is I click the other answer as well. Sorry for that

Comment: And I've added comment for toggle navigation thing above you can read that because that is not possible with Magento I guess.

Comment: Now, I can upvote

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100080/discussion-on-answer-by-kishan-savaliya-where-can-i-find-the-main-sidebar-file-l).

Answer (score 1):

`vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\account\navigation.phtml` is the main file which renders this list, it calls it child blocks to render the individual list items, so the items can be found in the layout file `vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout\customer_account.xml` passed as block arguments to child elements like below ;

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
                        </arguments>
</block>
```